# What should be a good design for the following scenario?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, kinect, software-design

We are recording the positions of various body parts. Our hardware (Microsoft Kinect)gives positions of as many as 20 Joints of Human Body. And it gives the data at about 30 fps.  Also position includes X, Y and Z co-ordinates of that particular joint. A particular gesture is of about 3-4 seconds so the no. of frames varies from 80 to 120. Our problem is to store and retrieve this data and to process it. Our terminology is as follows:

Frame: A snapshot of all the joints under consideration
Sample: Collection of all frames for a particular gesture

The problem is we are experimenting and we do not know how many joints’ data to be used in the project. So it is not fixed.

Now consider a particular problem of say storing the data.  The SQL Query is generated using the following method.
http://pastebin.com/ga114cQm

As you can see, the problem is there is lot of code repetition. In another problem where we have to preprocess the data, the same thing happens. Even though only 6 joints are preprocessed the length of the method is too much.
Have a look here: http://pastebin.com/JVKWNDmZ

Though it is working, I do not like it. Also, if we use encapsulation like filling objects instead of directly using arrays, how much performance hit will be there? Because this is a real-time gesture recognition system, we cannot afford a lot of delay.

If the Question is not very clear please tell me what part you did not understand. Since I did not want a very big question, I’ve tried to summarize the entire problem.

Comment: you should **use** the data that arrives, not store it, there's no time to do that. if you have to recognize a gesture, just discard everything that is not part of the gesture itself.

Comment: @vulkanino Yes, for recognition we are doing exactly that. But we need to store that date for training purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just to create a SQL `INSERT` instruction to store the values to the database, then your code makes no sense.

You could create a stored procedure in the db, set the parameters in the code and call the procedure, like:

```
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("InsertKinectData", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SkeletonX", sd.Position.X));
//...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

To optimize for speed, keep the db connection open, don't recreate the `SqlCommand` nor the parameters, just set the parameters with the new values as soon as they arrive, and call the SP immediately after.